# Scala - "Block cannot contain declarations"

Tags: scala

I'm am recently programming in Scala, and sometimes I have difficulties in solving some errors.

I want a Vector[Map[String, Any] and I'm trying to declare it in some function, and I get the error "Block cannot contain declarations". I already googled this problem but I don't understand the cause of this error.

```
def reproduce(selected: Vector[Map[String, Any]]): Vector[Map[String, Any]] ={
  var children : Vector[Map[String, Any]]] = Vector()
  var p1 : Map[String, Any] = Map()
  var p2 : Map[String, Any] = Map()
  var child : Map[String, Any] = Map("genome" -> null)
  for (i <- 0 to pop_size-1){
    p1 = selected(i)
    if (i%2 == 0){
      p2 = selected(i+1)
    }else{
      p2 = selected(i-1)
    }
    if(i == selected.size - 1) p2 = selected(0)
    child("genome") = crossover( p1("genome").asInstanceOf[Vector[Int]], p2("genome").asInstanceOf[Vector[Int]])
    child("genome") = point_mutation( child("genome").asInstanceOf[Vector[Int]])
    children = children :+ child
  }
  children
}
```

As I said before I get an error (Block cannot contain declarations) on line 2 (var children : Vector[Map[String, Any]]] = Vector())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many close-brackets on that line. It should be:

```
var children: Vector[Map[String, Any]] = Vector()
```

Or, better:

```
var children = Vector[Map[String, Any]]()
```

Comment: @flyist If this solved your problem, please let other people know by accepting it (click the check-mark on the left side of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints on your code to make it more idiomatic Scala, and a version that compiles without errors.

Avoid using `var` and create new values if necssary

Put `val`s as close as possible to first use

If you are building a collection, use `for`/`yield` rather than appending to a `var` collection

```
def reproduce(selected: Vector[Map[String, Any]]): Vector[Map[String, Any]] = {
  val children =
    for (i <- 0 until pop_size) yield {
      val p1 = selected(i)
      val p2 =
        if (i == selected.size - 1) {
          selected(0)
        } else if (i % 2 == 0) {
          selected(i + 1)
        } else {
          selected(i - 1)
        }

      val cross = crossover(p1("genome").asInstanceOf[Vector[Int]], p2("genome").asInstanceOf[Vector[Int]])

      Map[String, Any]("genome" -> point_mutation(cross))
    }

  children.toVector
}
```